# Does JPA support a kind of "Any" mapping for embeddable objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, persistence

I'm extending the data model of an Java application to include some kind of a *setting* facility. *Settings* in this application would basically be Strings or Numbers, no entities or other model objects.

My Question is what's the best way to map this requirement to JPA (Hibernate)?

I first thought about implementing a *Setting* class with properties for each desired type but maybe there is a way to use something like Hibernate's [Any](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping) mapping? The Problem with the *any* mapping seems to be that it is meant to express relations to *entities* not *embeddables*.

Any ideas?

**edit:**

To clarify the requirement. I want to persist variable data in a simple way, think about *C* style union or  a bean property of the *Object* type.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement a bit? I'm not sure I understood everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does JPA support a kind of “Any” mapping for embeddable objects?

To my knowledge, neither JPA nor Hibernate do support defining relation **to** embeddable which are not entities. Just in case, the JPA wikibook has a very interesting section on [embeddables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables).

If I misunderstood your question, please clarify (again), your goal is still not clear (at least for me). Maybe a "pseudo" example could help.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the JPA wikibook. The section on [Variable and Heterogeneous Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Variable_and_Heterogeneous_Relationships) did clarify that JPA does not support the kind of mapping I want but suggests that some JPA implementations may support something alike.